# Many to Many duplicate when saving entity with multiples words (ex. The government)

Tags: django

I got a question. I've a models with some M2M fields. My goal is to classify the text. After saving my text, my M2M starts classifying:

- create a new entry if it does not exist,
- add the entry if it already exists,

But I got an issue:

For simple word there is no duplicate but for multiple word (ex. Mr President or Christophe Colomb) I got an error with duplicate entry.

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    
    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = unique_slugify(self, slugify(self.name))
        super(Categories, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
...
class Post(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_user")
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
catego = models.ManyToManyField('Categories',blank=True, related_name='post_catego')
```

In the save method I got this:

```
for category in response.categories:
            current_category = Categories.objects.filter(name=category.name)
            current_post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.slug)
            
            if current_category.count()<1:
                create_category = self.catego.create(name=category.name)
                current_post.catego.add(create_category)
            else:
                existed_category = Categories.objects.get(name=category.name)
                current_post.catego.add(existed_category)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a glance at:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

max_length could be too short... That could be the reason of the mismatch

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
```